# Loop through array within array within array that could be infinitely deep

Tags: php, recursion

I need to loop through the following array - https://pastebin.com/zesX6SrY

I feel like the following process should work but it does not :(

```
foreach ($this->getFormJson() as $formElement) {
            
    $currentElement = $formElement;
            
    while ($this->elementContainsComponents($currentElement)) {
        $formQuestions[] = $this->getQuestionsFromComponent($currentElement);
        $currentElement = $this->getComponents($currentElement);
    }
}
```

The complex part of this is that each array could contain a 'components' array, which itself could contain a 'components' array etc etc

I am struggling to compose code that will loop through every 'components' array with the whole array itself

Comment: Looks like you want a *recursive*  function for that.